# Spring model isn't applied

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I have the following piece of the `jsp` markup:

```
<p>The name of the workplace is ${w}</p>
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController{

    @Autowired
    private WorkplacementDao workplacementDao;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(ModelMap m){
        String workplaceName = workplacementDao.getNameById(2);
        m.addAttribute("w", workplaceName);
        return "hello";
    }
   //...
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml is the following:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.maventestwebapp" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/introDB"/>
</bean>

<bean id="workplacementDao" class="com.mycompany.maventestwebapp.db.dao.WorkplacementDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Now when I request `/hello` page in my browser I just get:

```
The name of the workplace is ${w}
```

`${w}` wasn't replaced to its actual value. Why? What's wrong?

UPD: web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Enable EL processing, make sure your web.xml is a version 2.4 or up.

Comment: @M.Deinum How can I do that? Is it a special case of web.xml?

Comment: No make sure your header has the correct version, older versions don't have EL support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Spring problem. As suggested in the comments, your expressions aren't being evaluated because your web.xml doesn't specify a modern version of the Servlet/JSP APIs which supported that functionality.

Change your `web.xml` to start with :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <servlet>
    .....
```